# Rewriterule for index page in localhost

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I tried the below code for redirect any page to index page in localhost but somehow it is not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

Please help me to redirect to my site index page.

Answer (score 0):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
   IndexIgnore *
</IfModule>
```

Please make sure mod_rewrite module active in your httpd.conf file like:

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```